# Cohomology of De Rham complex with respect to different sites.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

Sheaf cohomology of algebraic De Rham complex gives the algebraic De Rham cohomology groups. This coincides with the singular cohomology if for example the variety is defined over $\mathbb{C}$. I was wondering whether taking sheaf cohomology of the De Rham complex with respect to different sites other than the Zariski topology gives any interesting cohomology groups? Especially I couldn't figure out what would be the cohomology groups in the case of etale topology?

Comment: You might want to look up crystalline cohomology. There's a whole constellation of theories that seem to revolve around doing de Rham cohomology in characteristic $p$, but I'm not the person to ask.

Comment: @user127776 - Cohomology in the etale topology gives the same result as cohomology in the zariski topology for quasi coherent sheaves: If $E$ is a quasi coherent sheaf on $X$, it follows $H^i_{et}(X_{et}, E_{et}) \cong H^i(X_{zar}, E_{zar})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The de Rham cohomology does not change if you replace the Zariski topology by the étale topology, at least for smooth schemes. More generally, for arbitrary schemes, the Hodge-completed derived de Rham cohomology does not change as long as the Grothendieck topology in question is coarser than the fpqc topology. The point is that, given a base ring $R$, the functor $\operatorname{Alg}_{R}\to \widehat{\operatorname{DF}}(R),A\mapsto\widehat{\operatorname{dR}}_{A/R}$ satisfies fpqc descent. This is (essentially) proved in Example 5.10 of

[B. Bhatt, M. Morrow, P. Scholze, *Topological Hochschild homology and integral $p$-adic Hodge theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03261).

Indeed, recall that the Hodge-completed derived de Rham cohomology is the completion of the derived de Rham cohomology with respect to the Hodge filtration. In order to see that the functor $A\mapsto\widehat{\operatorname{dR}}_{A/R}$ satisfies fpqc descent, it suffices to check that the associated graded pieces $A\mapsto\bigwedge_A^iL_{A/R}$ satisfies fpqc descent, which is Theorem 3.1 of *loc. cit.*